# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method , method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
     private void BindGrid()
     {

       AdvContextEF db = new AdvContextEF();

       var query = from r in db.mytable

       orderby r.CreateDate descending
       select new
       {
          r.id,
          r.code,
          r.mytable.relatedtables[0].TheCenter.Name

       };

        RadGrid1.DataSource = query.ToList();
        RadGrid1.DataBind();
    }
```

I got the following error when running the code above.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'AdvContextEF.mymethod get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to index into `r.mytable.relatedtables[0]`, try using `.FirstOrDefault()`.

```
      r.mytable.relatedtables.FirstOrDefault().TheCenter.Name
```

or

```
      Name = r.mytable.relatedtables.Select(rt => rt.TheCenter.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: you got the issue perfect.. it was problem with index